# Problem with reading file from module in Android Studio project

Tags: android, file, android-permissions

I wrote the simple module with java file that reads text data from .txt file. When I run this module everything is fine. But during the debugging session of using that module in the MainActivity.java file, I receive this flags that don't allow me to read data from this file:

```
DISALLOW_DISK_READ = 2
DISALLOW_DISK_WRITE = 1
threadPolicy = {BlockGuard$2@11269} 
PENALTY_LOG = 16
PENALTY_DIALOG = 32
PENALTY_DEATH = 64
PASS_RESTRICTIONS_VIA_RPC = 8
LAX_POLICY = {BlockGuard$1@11268} 
DISALLOW_NETWORK = 4
```

How to make it work, so I could for example read text as a string and put it as text in button?

This is my code: https://github.com/MaciejKamianowski/Projektowanie_Aplikacji_Android_Projekt

Comment: please add your code

Comment: https://github.com/MaciejKamianowski/Projektowanie_Aplikacji_Android_Projekt